# Node.js, Express Calling function twice, One with complete req.body, One with an empty body

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, express

So this is going to be hard to explain, ill try my best.
I have an iOS app and android that hits the same node.js app in their web view. The iOS web view opens the node.js app just fine. However, the android is having troubles. Ive tracked it down to a route function that is hit on:

```
 app.post('/', auth.processDeviceLogin);
```

On my auth page:

```
exports.processDeviceLogin = function(req, res){
var param;

if(typeof req.body.metaData !== 'undefined'){
    param = req.body;
}
else {
    //Android will hit this condition as items are not posted with application/json content type.
   param = JSON.parse(Object.keys(req.body));

}

auth.makeDeviceLoginRequestQ(
    stuff
).then(function(_data) {
        return moreStuff;
    })
    .then(function(_user){
        return againMoreStuff;
    })
    .spread(function(_user, token){
        //blah blah blah

        res.render('device', obj);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        res.json({status:"fail", reason:error});
    })
    .done();
};
```

Here is what I'm experiencing: When I debug the code and step through, I receive the first req correctly. All the headers/bodies/etc are received from the app. However, all of the sudden this function gets called again and the req info is mostly empty. The body is empty, some of the header information is there but the content-type is empty. It throws

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at exports.processDeviceLogin at the line

```
  param = JSON.parse(Object.keys(req.body))
```

This error suggests a simple syntax error, but I've debugged ALOT. I have even hard coded the same param value that i get from the iOS version, to no avail. Im guessing it has to do with that second empty req coming in from somewhere.

Both times this function is hit, the callee is(part of the Express router package):

```
Layer.prototype.handle_request = function handle(req, res, next) {
  var fn = this.handle;
  if (fn.length > 3) {
    // not a standard request handler
    return next();
}

 try {
    fn(req, res, next);
   } catch (err) {
   next(err);
   }
 };
```

I guess my question is, what would cause a second call to this function with empty request(req) values? Im completely lost. any help would be great.
Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

This `JSON.parse(Object.keys(req.body));` does not make any sense to me.

If `req.body` is a JSON string, then there's no point in calling `Object.keys()` on it because `Object.keys()` on a plain JS string won't give you anything useful.

If `req.body` is already a JS object, then you don't need to parse it.  And, you NEVER call `JSON.parse()` on the output of `Object.keys()` as that is passing a JS array to `JSON.parse()`.

This code just looks wrong.  `JSON.parse()` should be passed a JSON string.

What you could do instead is this:

```
if (typeof req.body === "string") {
    // if JSON string, then parse it
    param = JSON.parse(req.body);
} else if (typeof req.body === "object") {
    // if already parsed into an object, then get the keys
    param = Object.keys(req.body);
} else {
    // some sort of error handling here for unexpected data 
}
```

Comment: The reason for the above is because the req body I'm getting from the Android side looks like this, before and parsing or such:

Comment: { '{"actionInfo":{"type":"something"},"metaData":{"action":"GET","apiVersion":"2","appId":"something","appVersion":"2.5.7","appVersionCode": something,"language":"en_US","latitude": something,"longitude": something,"osVersion":"Android API 23","uniqueDeviceId":"something","brandedTo":"something","model":"unknown Android SDK built for x86_64 (generic_x86_64)","device":"Android 6.0"},"userData":{"sessionId":"something","authority":"ALL","userId":"something","type":"USER","anotherId":"something"}}': '' }

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is silly. The problem had to do with the version of the Android Emulator i was using. Marshmallow didn't work at all with this web view url post. Whereas Api 21 worked just fine. FYI, test different emulator types if this is your problem.